# Use openlayers-directive inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, openlayers

I'm trying to use openlayers-directive inside a directive:

```
var app = angular.module("demoapp", ["openlayers-directive"]);
app.directive('myDir', function () {
return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      template: "<openlayers ol-center='center' height='480px' width='640px'></openlayers>"
  }
})
```

In html:

```
<my-dir></my-dir>
```

But when I'm doing this, I have a multi-dir error

```
VM2731 angular.js:12221 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [myDir, openlayers] asking for template on: <openlayers ol-center="center" height="480px" width="640px">
```

Any explanation will be usefull

Thanks!

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ludocluba/jdzjow4h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive's template should have its own root `<div>`, inside it will be placed the `open-layers` directive. This way you're defining a separate template in which the nested directive can be compiled.

```
template: "<div><openlayers ol-center='center' height='480px' width='640px'></openlayers></div>"
```